# How do we know the existence of $M>0$ that makes $P(|X|=M)=0$? (probability theory and examples, Durrett, theorem 1.6.8)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a random variable. So can we choose a sufficiently large $M>0$ such that $P(|X|=M)=0$??

I know that if X is discrete then it is easy to find such M and that if X is continuous then clearly $P(|X|=M)=0$ by some properties of continuous distribution. However, there is no information about continuous distribution in this book. So I wonder exactly why I can choose M.

[image]

Comment: $P(|X|=M)>\frac 1 n$ for at most $n$ values of $M$. Alternatively, a distribution function is dis-continuous at at most countably many points.

Comment: Then there will be at most countably many values of M.